# How to get the selected chip of angular-material chips?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

You can select the `md-chip` elements in `md-chips` by clicking on them, but I haven't found a good method to find out which one got selected in the controller.

Has anyone accomplished this?

```
<md-chips ng-model="ctrl.roFruitNames">
  <md-chip-template>
    <strong>{{$chip}}</strong>
    <em>(fruit)</em>
  </md-chip-template>
</md-chips>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbOaLz

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately as far as I can see in Angular Material's code, this is not exposed in the current implementation of `md-chip`.

You can get around it by accessing the directive's controller directly, but it's quite dirty, and will easily break with future versions of `md-chip`.

```
<md-chips ng-model="ctrl.roFruitNames" ng-click="ctrl.getSelectedChip($event)">
```

In the controller:

```
self.getSelectedChipIndex = function(event) {       
  var selectedChip = angular.element(event.currentTarget).controller('mdChips').selectedChip;
  alert(selectedChip);
}
```

See it working:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXopQq

There is already an issue in Angular Material requesting something like this, so hopefully it will be added in the future:

https://github.com/angular/material/issues/3413

---

*[Edit]*

to fetch chip data:

```
 var ctrl = angular.element(event.currentTarget).controller('mdChips');

  if(ctrl !== undefined){
     var selectedChip = ctrl.items[ctrl.selectedChip];
  }
```

Comment: The issue is acutally from me haha, but thanks anyways your solution will do for now!

Comment: Really ask myself how the material design team is planning controls. Can`t be on a real life base.

Answer (score 12):

Use **md-on-select :** An expression which will be called when a chip is selected.

```
 <md-chips md-on-select="getChipInfo($chip)" md-on-remove="removeChip($chip)"> ... </md-chip>
```

In your controller

```
$scope.getChipInfo= function(chip_info) {
console.log(chip_info);
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, I have tested it and it works great.  However, I do feel the need to add a bit of information.  Use md-transform-chip="vm.transformChip($chip)" to capture the moment when the text you type and select from the dropdown is "transformed" into a chip.  To me, this is more useful than md-on-select

Comment: If you have `readonly="true"` set it to false and this works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried md-chips' `md-on-select`? In the Codepen you shared you're using Angular Material v0.10, with which `md-on-select` doesn't work, but if you change it to v0.11.4, it does work:

```
<md-chips md-on-select="ctrl.select($chip)">
```

In controller:

```
self.select = function(chip) {
  // You got the chip!
}
```

Here's a forked version of your Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLmKQR

MD Chips' API: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdChips

Just a side note, if `md-on-add` doesn't work, use `md-on-append` instead, although it will be removed on official v1.0 release.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a function in your scope with `ng-click`:

```
<md-chip-template ng-click="ctrl.doSomething($chip)" >
```

Comment: Unfortunately this only works in a limited way, because you have to click on the text part to trigger the "event" and the chip does not get selected.

Answer (score 0):

It should be md-on-add

```
<md-chips md-on-add="ctrl.select($chip)">
```

or

```
<md-chips md-on-add="yourmodel=ctrl.chipModel">
```